# Lead Sharing within Teams

Tags: administration, admin, sales, system-admin

I am in a fix, looking for some Salesforce admin support on Lead Sharing. We  got high numbers of TLs & then thier Teams. Sharing/Access to leads with Role hierarchy or creating groups would be an endless list. I am looking for TLs should only see and edit leads owned by their team. Is there any other way to achieve this without using Role hierarchy or creating groups.

Apex Managed Sharing does not work for Standard Objects.

Please suggest.

Comment: This is the very purpose of the Role Hierarchy. I hear you that it would be lots of roles, but that may be the only way to do it.

Comment: Thanks David! Can we use LeadShare here for this purpose. Please suggest.

Comment: Please don't use LeadShare. You will have so many entries on that table that it could slow things down. Use the role hierarchy, as that's what it is intended for. It will save on repeated calculations.